# Magento 2 Import Product custom option drop down values in bulk

Tags: magento2, custom-options

There are some product in my portal and these products require to add custom options of drop down type whose values range is from 1-10000.If we are going to add it one by one it will take so much time.

Can anybody suggest how to do it in bulk?

Comment: Custom options in product attribute dropdown ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal,yes custom option drop down values in bulk,